# Nonzero function of zero norm in Hilbert space

Tags: vector-spaces

Does the function,

$$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{matrix}1 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ if }x=0\\
0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ \text{ if }x\ne0
\end{matrix}
\right.$$

belong to $L^p$? If yes, how do we reconcile the fact that this function has a zero norm, with the fact that the function itself is not zero?

Comment: The function is almost everywhere zero. Are you sure you understand what an element of $L^p$ is? An element of $L^p$ is not a function. It's a class.

Comment: Just to add a remark- $L^p$ is NOT a Hilbert space, unless $p=2$.

Answer (score 5):

The reconciliation is that an element in $L^p$ is NOT an function- but equivalence class of functions. Your function is equivalent to the $0$ function. (I am assuming that you are using the Lebesgue measure- the equivalence relation is equal upto sets of measure $0$).